# using data placeholders in Social Bu

Tags: json, replace, placeholder, jsonplaceholder

I'm using Social Bu to monitoring my Social Media Accounts
And I want to setting automation recipe
That send slack immediately If there's any facebook post via social bu.

So I set http request (POST) to my slack channel.

I wrote a code like below to send response to my slack as a text.

```
{"text": {{ action_1_2.response }}}
```

But there's a error message like :

```
The body must be a valid JSON string.
```

How can i send a response as a text using data placeholders?

[image: socialbu automation ui]

[image: data placeholders]